# Initialize a variable which is not in the class in react js

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way I can initialize MYGLOBALVARIABLE from the props received So that I can use it in other functions which are not in class ?
Edit : Actually I am calling function PQR from class ABC. Function XYZ further calls function XYZ. So instead of passing the argument again and again, I want to declare a const to be used by each function.

```
          const MYGLOBALVARIABLE; //VARIABLE-TO-BE-INITIALIZED

                type Props = {
                  var1: string;
                }

                type State = {

                }

                class ABC extends React.Component {
                  props: Props;
                  state: State;
                  constructor(props: Props) {
                    super(props);
                    this.state = getDefaultState(props);
                  }

                  render() {
     --------- Here I wat to Initialize MYGLOBALVARIABLE to props.var1 ---

                 //Call PQR()

                    return (
                      <div> //Something </div>
                    );
                  }

              function PQR(){
                  calls XYZ()
                }
                function EFG(){
                   uses MYGLOBALVARIABLE;
                }
```

Comment: Sure. Use `let` instead of `const`. As long as it exists in `EFG`'s scope it'll work fine. Consider, though, that this might be a code smell and there's a good chance you'll be better off rethinking the relationship between `MYGLOBALVARIABLE`, `ABC`, and `EFG`. Since you haven't given us any details, however, so it's impossible to say what the right approach is here.

Comment: Actually I am calling function PQR from class ABC. Function XYZ further calls function XYZ. So instead of passing the argument again and again, I want to declare a const to be used by each function.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help you if you showed us what problem you're actually trying to solve, instead of using fake code with names like ABC and PQR. This seems a lot like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/140350), but we don't have enough information to know either way.